# How to send http requests dynamically in Gatling?

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling

I'm trying to save some seq in static variable and then make http get for each value of the seq:

```
.exec { session =>
    residents = session("residents").as[String]
    .split(",").toSeq
    .map(f => f.replaceAll("\"", ""))
    session
}
.foreach(residents, "resident") {
    exec(http("resident").get("#{resident}"))
}
```

Each element of seq is http url.

Is it possible to send http requests dynamically in Gatling depends on count of seq elements? How can I do this beacuse this code doesn't work as I expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how Gatling works.
Your residents mutable reference is:

- global to your test, hence you'll face race conditions when running with multiple users
- not populated at the time you're building your `foreach` action

You've pulled `residents` from the current user's `Session`, you must stay in this scope:

```scala
.exec { session =>
    val residentsSeq = session("residents").as[String]
    .split(",").toSeq
    .map(f => f.replaceAll("\"", ""))
    // replace the original "residents" with a Seq
    session.set("residents", residentsSeq)
}
// basically equivalent to
// foreach(session => session("residents").as[Seq[String]], "resident")
.foreach("#{residents}", "resident") {
    exec(http("resident").get("#{resident}"))
}
```